# How to stop a javascript from execution and allow user to save a form

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript method for validating a form. But under a certain condition, control should stop the script and allow the user to save a form.

Will `'return'` keyword work here?

```
if(matchSearch==null)
    {
        alert('Mismatch in Subsidiary and Year. Stopping script to allow form submission.');
        return;
    }
```

The idea is, `if matchSearch == null`, script should stop and user should be allowed to save the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you have a function that has been assigned as an `onsubmit` handler, i.e., the function is called when the user tries to submit, then `return;` as in your example will stop execution of the function and allow the submission to continue.

Any `return` statement will exit from the current function. The value that you return *might* matter depending on how the submit handler was assigned: `return false;` from an inline `onsubmit=""` attribute will prevent the form from being submitted. Your `return;` statement without a value implicitly returns `undefined` which won't prevent submission.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check form fields before the the form is submitted, the (submit) handler function that does the check should return false. That way the submit is cancelled, and the form stays on the screen, retaining the values a user already typed. Something like:

```
function checkValues(){
  //check values
  if (/*return value of the check is wrong*/){
    // save form functionality
    return false
  }
  // check ok
  return true;
}
yourform.onsubmit = checkValues;
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz4pR/) for a very basic example

Alternatively you can also program a 'listener' function that checks the contents of every form field periodically. You can find an example in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9ssKZ/). It is designed to show a submit button only if all fields have valid values.

Answer (score -2):

Using `return false;` will stop the execution of the script.